# Как сделать динамическую страницу с tableview?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Всем доброго времени суток.
Хотелось бы узнать как сделать страницу на которой есть label, image, tableview и чтобы они вместе скролились, исходя из того на сколько большой tableview
Вот в пример как на макете:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я делаю я видимо неправильно расставляю констрейнты, получается так что страница скроллится сама tableview сама, когда отключаю scrolling enabled то tableview становится статичным
Подскажите как настроить tableview чтобы можно было его листать вместе со всем контейнером и он будет отображать столько новостей, сколько есть в массиве?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете поместить все Label's и ImageView в одну View, а потом добавить их к tableHeaderView как показано на скриншоте. В таком случае ваша View будет скроллится вместе с контентом TableView

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Это как раз то что мне нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1) Сделать отдельную View, куда ты положишь свои ImageView и Labels и назначить ее как **tableHeaderView**.

2) Сделать **отдельную ячейку для таблицы**, которая будет идти первой, в которой будет ваш ImageView и Labels

3) Это зависит от ваших целей, но если все вьюшки ваши разнотипны и из количество не сильно велико, то можно использовать **StackView, который вы положите в ScrollView**.